# What are different between Rename package and Rename directory in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I add a new module for a project in Android Studio. I hope to rename package, so I select *Refactor* -> *Rename item*, you can see Image 1.

I find that the Image 2 is displayed to let me select between *Rename package* and *Rename directory*, I'm confused.

I think that the name of package and the name of directory are matched, I think that the name of directory will be changed when I change the name of package, and the name of package must be changed when I change the name of directory.

And more, the Image 3 is displayed when I add a new module for the project, I don't know what *Application/Library* name mean, I can't find the string *My Library* in whole project.

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

**Image3**

[image]

**Added  Content**

To oiyio: Thanks!

But the file *string.xml* file isn't be created automatically when I create a new module for the project, so  I can't find the string *My Library* in  *string.xml*.

You can see the tree structure with Image 4, and you download the code at https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwhjb7vq4hfxfi8/MyTest.zip?dl=0 for test.

**Image 4**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Rename package will rename all the files which have package name imported with the new package name and rename directory will rename the directory folder and will not change the package name which is imported in each file.